# How fix Application Loader errors from apps made with Flash Pro

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air, compiler-errors

I am on Mac using Flash Pro.  I have successfully designed and published an IOS app, and compiled it into the .ipa file, but when I try to upload it with Application Loader it gives me this error:

    *ERROR ITMS-9000: "This bundle is invalid. New apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 5 and iOS 7 SDK." at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)*

I have seen across the web ways to fix this for *Flash Builder* but nothing for *Flash Pro*.  
Am I missing some update or does apple just not accept apps made with Flash Pro anymore?
Is it possible to "overlay" flash pro over Xcode and how would I go about doing this?

Version Info:
Mac OS X 10.9
Flash Pro 13.1.0.226
Air 3.8 for IOS
ActionScript 3.0

Comment: What do you mean 'application loader'? And what do you mean 'upload'? Where are you trying to put your .ipa? Have you tried to test it on an iOS device by importing it into the iTunes library and installing it onto an iPhone or iPad? What type of provisioning profile are you using?  Why not help us by giving some real information?

Comment: Application Loader what you use to upload apps to the Apple appstore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **must** use the latest version of the AIR 4.0 SDK in order to publish to the iTunes Store. 3.9 added support for iOS 7 and as of February 1, all apps **must** be published using Xcode 5, and support for that was not added until the latest 4.0 update (which was pushed out of beta and into production late last week).

So update from AIR 3.8 to 4.0 (make sure you test!) and then try publishing again. This should solve the issues. Additionally, 3.9 added support for the new iOS app icon sizes, so you will have to create a new icon as well.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html